# Are vector functions uniquely determined by their partial derivatives up to some constant?

Tags: derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative, jacobian

Conceptual question.
I'm thinking about this because I'm studying directional derivatives in differential geometry.

Are vector functions uniquely determined by their partial derivatives up to some constant?

Even kind of more specifically, are vector functions uniquely determined by their Jacobian (up to a constant)?

I would think that they are because of the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I just haven't seen anything that answers my question and I'm pretty new to the material.

I do understand that directional derivatives are linear transformations and that they consider a very geometric relationship. Specifically, they consider the relationship between a collection of curves in the domain associated with some point and the corresponding initial velocities of the transformations of those vectors.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: What's your definition of a vector function? Are we in a Banach space $V$ and consider functions $V\to V$, or are we in a manifold $M$ and consider sections $M\to TM$?

Comment: So I'm working in differential geometry. I'm considering functions from $R^m$ to $R^n$.

Comment: Then you can use the argument from 1d analysis: differentiable functions whose differential is $0$ are locally constant (that is constant on connected domains). If two functions have identical differential, then their difference has the differential $0$, so their difference is locally constant. So differentiable vector fields on connected domains are uniquely defined by their differential up to an additive constant.